# How can I insert a row in all tables in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

I haven't been able to find an easy solution for this but I'm pretty sure there is somewhere. How can I add a row to all tables in a database?

For instance if I had two tables A and B how can I add (insert?) row C into both tables?

**EDIT:** All of the tables have the same structure.

Comment: Do all the tables have the same structure?

Comment: You are doing it wrong, but you can do a Trigger on insert A: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/triggers.html

Comment: Tables with the same structure is a clear code smell indicating that you have not designed the database correctly.

Comment: @HLGEM don’t be condescending it doesn’t help you or members of Stack Overflow, this is an old question but an important one. Focus on quality contributions, not quantity.

Comment: @HLGEM Wrong. You don’t know that as a certainty. If you actually wanted to contribute you’d post an answer with a structural suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no statement that will insert into more than one table at the same time.

You will have to find out the table names that you want to insert data into, and issue an insert statement for each of them. You can do that within a single transaction, though.

Also note that usually different tables in the database have different schema, so that you may not be able to insert the exact same row into all of them.

Also note that there is an influential school of relational database designers that tries to avoid duplication (because it wastes storage and can lead to inconsistencies when later updates are not applied properly). They would not like the idea of storing the same piece of data in multiple locations.